# How to Open a newly Created Excel WOrkBook as Active Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-automation

I have developed an Addin in Excel. This addin has a ribbon that contains a button. When this button is clicked, I create a new work book and work sheet based on an xml string that is retrived from the database based on the user credential.
Iam able to create the workbook along with the work sheets, however, this work book is not displayed as the  primary work book for the user.

What I would like to acheive is : When the addin is clicked on an excel work book , the generated work book shall become the active one and the old excel work book goes visually so that the users attention is now focussed on the created work sheet instead of him having to search for the created work book.

Here is the code that I have used, but it does not seem to work : 
Ps : Iam using Excel 2013 and VS 2013 and C#

```
var excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application; 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook newWorkBook = null; 
newWorkBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add(); 
#region BringGeneratedWorkBookToFront 
string newWorkBookName = newWorkBook.Name; 
foreach (Workbook wb in excel.Workbooks){ 
   if (wb.Name == newWorkBookName) { 
      wb.Activate(); 
      break; 
   } 
}
#endregion
```

Comment: in your code you are looping through all the workbooks and activating each one.  You should post the code that creates the workbook and the click event handler

Comment: Hi,  Iam checking for the work book based on the name and only when there is a name match , I do an activate.

Comment: Here is the code :                       var excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook newWorkBook = null;
newWorkBook =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add(); #region BringGeneratedWorkBookToFront
 string newWorkBookName = newWorkBook.Name;
 foreach (Workbook wb in excel.Workbooks){
  if (wb.Name == newWorkBookName)
                 {
                     wb.Activate();
                     break; 
                 }
             }
            #endregion

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code simplified:

```
Excel.Workbook newWorkBook =Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add();
newWorkBook.Activate();
```

Comment: Hi , Using this code does not bring the newly created excel to the front. the excel  work book from which the addin was called still remains in focus, what i want to acheive is that the newly created excel work book comes in focus

Comment: @Anand, Are you using an Application-Level Addin or a Document-Level Addin?<br/>Also, what's about setting the workbook visibility to true, like this: newWorkBook.Windows[1].Visible = true;